# Why would $(document).on('click', [selectors]) work but not $([selectors]).on('click')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason changing the format of the below jQuery event handler code for a larger .js file seems to make the on click event work, but technically both ways should be valid.

```
$('[data-onclick="flyTo"], [data-onclick="flyToAndClick"], [data-onclick="flyToThenClick"], [data-onclick="flyToAndAction”]’).on(‘click’, function(e) {
```

vs

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-onclick="flyTo"], [data-onclick="flyToAndClick"], [data-onclick="flyToThenClick"], [data-onclick="flyToAndAction"]', function(e) {
```

This seems like such a trivial change, but I really want to understand what's happening here.

Cheers for any help!

Comment: Replace all `“` and `”` by `"`, and all `‘` and `’` by `'`. Both statements have different meanings. Are the selected elements always the same or are they dynamically changed? The second snippet uses event delegation, the first one does not.

Comment: See also the [official jQuery documentation](//api.jquery.com/on#direct-and-delegated-events).